# Android Vector Drawable with ImageView: the image is being cutted at the bottom

Tags: android, android-imageview, vector-graphics, android-vectordrawable

I have the following svg (vector file):

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="18dp"
    android:height="3dp"
    android:viewportWidth="8.64"
    android:viewportHeight="1.44">
  <path
      android:fillColor="#363636"
      android:pathData="M0.72,0C0.3223,0 0,0.3224 0,0.72s0.3223,0.72 0.72,0.72 0.72,-0.3224 0.72,-0.72S1.1177,0 0.72,0Z" />
  <path
      android:fillColor="#363636"
      android:pathData="M4.3201,0C3.9224,0 3.6,0.3224 3.6,0.72s0.3224,0.72 0.7201,0.72c0.3976,0 0.72,-0.3224 0.72,-0.72S4.7177,0 4.3201,0Z" />
  <path
      android:fillColor="#363636"
      android:pathData="M7.9199,0C7.5224,0 7.2,0.3224 7.2,0.72s0.3224,0.72 0.72,0.72c0.3977,0 0.7201,-0.3224 0.7201,-0.72S8.3177,0 7.9199,0Z" />
</vector>
```

Used in the ImageView:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="1dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/back_button"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_left_black"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="@string/avatar"
                    android:textColor="#313131"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/menu_button"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_more" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

The preview of vector file looks just fine:
[image]

However in ImageView, the vector file looks like it's bottom was cuted and flatened, it's not a cricle any more:
[image]
[image]

Am I using vector drawable and svg incorrectly?

Comment: This could be related to rounding problems: viewPort height1.44 was probably rounded down to 1 (hence the cropping).  Try using integer viewport values like `android:viewportWidth="9" android:viewportHeight="2"`.

Comment: Try scaling with `fitCenter`.